# JBoss v4.2 in Eclipse, getting config parsing exceptions

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I'm trying to start my JBoss v4.2 server in Eclipse, but I'm getting some exceptions. [Here's the log](http://codepad.org/mYQCT13K). Any clues what the problem might be? The only file the log lists is the `jboss-service.xml` file, and I don't see any problems with that.

So, the problem is that my `java.security` file points to a `nss.cfg` file which contains a ~ in it as follows:

`nssLibraryDirectory = C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jdk1.6.0_32/bin`

I could change that to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_32/bin`, but it doesn't like parenthesis either. So I have to find some way to link to the folder without having any parenthesis or tildes.

Solved my problem for now. I copied the bin folder to a folder without any special characters (`C:\javabin`). A *hopefully* temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error is described here:

```
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.ConfigurationException: Unexpected value Token['~'], line 2
    at sun.security.pkcs11.Config.excToken(Config.java:339)
```

It looks like you need to use XML code to represent the ~

Can you post the XML configuration?

Comment: By XML configuration, do you mean the `jboss-service.xml` file? Or something else?

Answer (score -1):

Using an XML generated file (with **freemarker**) with [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) tags will escape properly these characters.

It must work. I know it could be heavy at the first time, but you will do this one time per server implementation, and run it as much as you need these server implementation e.g. jboss 4.2.2 GA...

XML encoding is good too, but your XML file is not really human-readable after that.

To think about generated file, you could take the default `jboss-service.xml` and build it as a template `jboss-service.ftl` and you can generate it as many time you need a configuration update.

I think you could encode XML chars on the fly with freemarker too with the method `to_xml("name",object)` and look at [Build-ins for Nodes (XML)](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_node.html)... if you choose these way to go.